# Rendering of Raleway (Google Web Fonts) in Google Chrome browser

Tags: fonts, google-chrome, windows, windows-7

I am using **Windows 7** and I have a problem with one of Google Fonts: **Raleway**. I checked and this font looks very good in **Firefox** (ver. 34) but in **Google Chrome** (ver. 39) it looks terrible on my computer. Sometimes I cannot read the text.

I downloaded **Raleway** Google Web Fonts thanks to this link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway%3A200%2C300%2C400%2C500%2C600%2C700&#038;subset=latin">
```

---

**Print screens** (Windows 7):

Google Web Font: **Raleway** in Google **Chrome** 39

[image: GWF Raleway in Google Chrome (Windows 7)]

Google Web Font: **Raleway** in **Firefox** 34

[image]

---

Raleway, Google Web Font you can find on http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Raleway

Comment: There are some issues with chrome and google fonts also. To solve this issue you can do : download font all forms [woff, ttf, svg etc] , create font face kit and call it using @font-face in css file. Also upload font face kit to your server.

Comment: Google file contains **CSS code**, which download required font files (e.g. in Chrome it is "**.woff2**"). Part of this code is below. I do not understand what is the difference between using font files from Google server and from my server if principle of operation is the same. 

On the other hand I am using it in **WP theme** where user can change the font and I cannot include all Google fonts to **WP theme**, that is why I need to use standard solution using link to **CSS** (with **@font-face**) generated by **fonts.googleapis.com**.

Comment: BTW
in **CSS file** from **fonts.googleapis.com** when I start it in Chrome I have code like this:
`@font-face {(...) src: local('Raleway'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/raleway/(...)N8.woff2) format('woff2');`

Comment: I don't see this at all. Is it fixed? If not, can you give me a link to an example page?

Comment: I want to add that I have this problem on my computers (every where I see Raleway font), but I do not see this issue on other computers :|

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue with Raleway and some versions of Chrome, it's related to anti-aliasing of fonts. This is a fix for windows, using SVG in the css

```
/*FIX FONT FOR GOOGLE CHROME ON WINDOWS*/
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('fonts/myfont.svg#myfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;}
 }
```

This can make things look even worse on a Mac so you can code HTTP headers to change this only for Windows, [instructions](https://www.domsammut.com/code/some-solutions-to-font-face-rendering-poorly-in-windows-google-chrome)

This suggestion `html { -webkit-text-stroke: 0.25px}` from [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/570592/469963) looks promising.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22075072/4258817) from stackoverflow explains how to get around issues involving locally installed google fonts and chrome rendering.

[chrome bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152304) and [news on Chrome 37 fixing it](http://const.fr/chrome-webfonts-antialiasing-fixed/)